# Understanding Multithreading and execution process

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm not clear on the process that CLR performs when running a program.  I'm not quite clear on when to use lock() or some other type of thread safe objects.

Please help me understand the following:

Having this code:

```
    public class Person {
        string Name {get;set;}
    }


public class Calc {
    public string DoStuff(Person p){
        // perform some processing on person object
        // maybe call external API and update person object
    }

}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but this is my understanding of Example 1. In single threaded app (suppose it's a mvc application and I'm using DI and already registered "Service" in the container.

I call Service.Work() from somewhere in my application.  new Calc() is created (CLR allocates this object in memory) and Calc.DoStuff() does computation on Person object. Since before the call new Calc() is created and get called from two browsers they are in separate execution paths. Is this correct?

```
// Example 1
public class Service {
    public void Work(person) {
       var calc = new Calc();
       string test = calc.DoStuff(person);
    }
}

// Example 2
public class Service {  
    public Service() {
        var calc = new Calc(); // this is different
    }   
    public void Work(person) {
        string test = calc.DoStuff(person);
    }
}
```

Now what happens in the same scenario, however this time at the time of allocating Service in memory Calc is instantiated in the Service's constructor. Would that cause problems with to simultaneous calls to Work() (since there is only ONE instance of Calc? object.

- What happens then? Would string name be populated with the "latest" string?).
- Would lock be required here so that first it has to finish 1st calls request then second?
- What happens when two browsers call Work(Person) sending two instances of Person to that method. Suppose Person objects goes "inside" Calc class and then an external API is called - and stalls for a bit. Then second request is called to Calc(Person) would this Person object be updated independently (even though there is only one instance of Calc()?). Or would the first request (the one that stalled) be cancelled by the second and forgotten?

Comment: "So If two browsers execute Calc.DoStuff()..." - You mentioned browsers.  Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: yes and no - Because it could be browsers but it could be that two different components of the application call Service.Work() at the same time. Does that make a difference? if it's Asp.net or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where your intuition went wrong:

> Now what happens in the same scenario, however this time at the time
>   of allocating Service in memory Calc is instantiated in the Service's
>   constructor. Would that cause problems with to simultaneous calls to
>   Work() (since there is only ONE instance of Calc? object.

Each call to the Service function has its own thread stack, and thus separate copies of all local variables.

For all intents and purposes, just picture the two browser requests as two totally separate programs.

Comment: I thought there is only one thread stack?. Does the same apply to Console App. Suppose you call Service from two "areas" of console app at the same time

Comment: No.  Those two browser requests are being handled simultaneously by separate threads in the web server.

Comment: In a Console app, you would by default only have one thread, and so only one call to Service would happen at a time.  If you created two threads, to call Service at the same time, each would have its own stack.

Comment: so CLR does it's own thread safety check? What you're saying is this: suppose I have bunch of other "services" that do some work, and occasionally they call Service.Work(Person) with different instances of Person. There would never be an instance that Person would get corrupted. correct?

Comment: No, it's not an issue of thread safety.  If your Service() method accessed a shared resource (a file on the server, a global variable, etc.) then you would need to manually add your locking code to prevent concurrency issues.  But your example doesn't explicitly show any shared resources.  The `Calc` object is a *local* variable in Service.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in both scenarios you should not expect that instance of Calc is single (singleton), so your DoStuff method needs to have synchronization of some kind, like `lock(p)`, for example, if instance of class Person is the same for all calls.